# Interface: Setter without a Getter

Tags: c#

I came across an interface recently that only defined a setter like so:

```
public interface IAggregationView
{
   DataTable SetSiteData { set; }
}
```

I queried this, and it is believed that this is one of the practices advocated by Microsoft for WebPart design (for SharePoint). In fact this example is directly copied from their examples.

I see this as a bad pattern, I don't see why someone should be able to set a value, and then not be able to read it again, and I believe a setter should always be accompanied with a getter (but not necessarily the other way around).

I'm wondering if anyone can explain the benefit of only having a setter, why Microsoft might be suggesting it in this case, and if it's really a good pattern to be following?

Comment: I would guess it's the same as not providing a setter. The setter in that case is private set by default. Probably the same for the getter too.

Comment: If not duplicate then may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695551/write-only-properties-whats-the-point

Comment: It is an unusual pattern, certainly; as is naming a property with a `Set...` prefix.

Comment: It's useless. Even MSDN documentation states one should not use them. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006.aspx

Comment: @Habib: Thanks Habib, indeed it is related and I'll have a read of that. I think this goes a bit further because I'd like to know why Microsoft have suggested it in this case.

Comment: This is not a write-only property. So not a dupe.

Comment: @danish Useless is subjective. The setter only property could as well have been a `public void SetProperty(PropertyType value)` but maybe properties setters are more desired in a particular situation then using methods when it comes to reflection. As a property setter has only 1 parameter, the value. As where methods can have more than 1 parameter. I wouldn't state this as useless. I do think it is unusual and there must be a good reason if you want to use it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two scenarios I can see where this might be reasonable:

1. it is not *possible* get the value, for example a password; however, I would replace that with a `void SetPassword(string)` method, personally
2. the API it is designed for *has no requirement* to ever read the value, and it is being restricted purely to expose the minimum required API

Re my first point, a `Set...` *method* may not be ideal if the consuming API is essentially an automated mapper that assigns values to properties; in that scenario properties would indeed be preferable.

Re your "I don't see why someone should be able to set a value, and then not be able to read it again" - by the same point, however, it could be argued that someone setting the value *already knows the value* (they set it), so they have no **requirement** to do this.

But yes; it is very unusual to have a set-only property.

Comment: I like your password example actually, that is a good clear case of where you might want to do this, but personally would also opt for a method. Nice answer.

Comment: If you expect at least some implementing classes to optionally add a getter, then it makes sense to have it as a setter instead of a `SetFoo` method. Interfaces don't stand alone, they represent a common subset of the operations on a family of classes. So you have to look at the extant classes, as well as the code that consumes the interfaces, to decide if the interface design makes sense.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker yes, but when the interface API isn't a direct subset of the class's public API, there's always *explicit interface implementation*

Comment: I agree, there *is* a more complicated way to achieve the same thing. :)

Answer (score 15):

The role of `get` and `set` in interface properties is slightly different from those in classes.

```
public interface IAggregationView
{
   DataTable SetSiteData { set; }
}

class AggregationViewImp : IAggregationView
{
   public DataTable SetSiteData { get; set; }  // perfectly OK
}
```

The interface specifies that the property should *at least* have a public setter. The definition and accessibility of the getter is left to the implementing class.

So if the interface contract only needs to write, `get` can be left open. No need to demand a public getter.

As a consequence, you cannot really specify a read-only property in interfaces either. Only 'at least read access'.

```
interface IFoo
{
    int Id { get;  }
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }  // protected/private set is OK too
}
```

Comment: Equally importantly "Foo" is *internal* thus properly encapsulating the implementation inside its immediate scope.

Answer (score 5):

I can imagine using it for (manual) dependency injection. A class may need to have a collaborator injected that it only uses internally. Of course one would normally choose to do this in the class' constructor, but there may be times when one would wish to change the collaborator at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Classes that implement the interface may add a getter. Most uses of the property may be via an implementing class, not via the interface itself. In which case most code has the ability to get and set the property. The only reason for the interface may be that there is some common code that accesses a common subset of the methods/properties of a family of classes. That code only requires the setter, not the getter. The interface documents that fact.

An interface is just a facility for declaring a group of operations that are "atomically needed" (e.g. if you need to call method A, you'll need to read property B and set property C).

So as always, *it depends*.

Answer (score 1):

In my experiences such interfaces crop up due to some special need, not for architectural reasons. For example in ASP.NET applications people sometimes make the Global.asax generated type derive from such an interface when they want to maintain global state. Someone might create an initialization value in a separate part of the application and need to publish it to a global place.

I usually like to replace a set-only property with a `SetXxx` method and make the method check that it is called at most once. That way I clearly enforce "initialization style" which is much less of a smell (imho).

Certainly one cannot set to *never* produce such a thing but it is to be avoided and will certainly raise questions during code review.