# Why using only setter in property declaration?

Tags: c#, .net

```
int MyProperty { set; }
```

What's the idea for using only setter on property? If we set one property with some value, I guess it's very likely to read this value at some point ?

Comment: Very unlikely, actually.

Comment: Does this compile?? Would be quite senseless...

Comment: That could only be part of an `interface`, in its current form, it doesn't compile otherwise.

Comment: Maybe if I use this property to set another object's property ?

Comment: @DTs: Are you actually seeing this usage somewhere, or inquiring theoretically? I cannot see a use for this construct, but if you are looking at exisiting then code more details of the context might teach us all something new.

Comment: Property without getter works same as `void method`. I would use property if its the only function is to set value of private field, because it looks **nicer** (for me at least) and is not at all less cleaner. And idea behind is to define property, not something else, which then will be used (more likely after adduction some class to interface).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write-only properties are rare in the Base Class Library, but [XmlReaderSettings.XmlResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.xmlresolver.aspx) is one example. Based on the security note in that topic, I believe the get accessor was omitted to prevent partially trusted code from accessing or tampering with the default resolver.

[XmlResolver.Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlresolver.credentials.aspx) and [XmlTextReader.XmlResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.xmlresolver.aspx) are probably write-only properties for the same reason.

(Strangely, [XmlAttribute.InnerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.innertext.aspx) is also a write-only property, but this doesn't seem to be good design.)

Following the above examples, I'd say you should use a write-only property **only** when a read-write property would otherwise make sense, but you don't want a get accessor for security reasons.

You could of course use a `Set` method instead, but a property has the advantage that it can be used in an object initializer, as is commonly done with `XmlReaderSettings`.

Comment: But that's not an auto-implemented property, it's a manually implemented property, which allows the value to change state visible at some scope.

Comment: @Servy: I assumed the OP was merely illustrating a property with no public or protected get accessor. For example, this is how MSDN Library documents my example: `public XmlResolver XmlResolver { set; }`. An automatic property must define both get and set accessors.

Comment: @Servy Auto implemented properties can't only have a setter, they must have some kind of getter. Try to compile an auto-implemented property with just a setter...

Answer (score 0):

You normally don't create a property like this. As you say, it doesn't have much value.

If you really want to allow only setting a certain value without reading it, then provide a method. That's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to have an auto-property with only a setter.  It can make sense to have a manually implemented property with only a setter that can then set a field used internally, but not visible externally.

Having a set only property is very uncommon, and are often implemented with a set method instead of a property as a set-only property is not expected behavior for most developers.

In fact, it is a compiler error for an auto-implemented property to define a `set` without a `get`.  A set-only property *must* be manually defined.

Answer (score 0):

A method would make much more sense than a 'write only property' - even if the code did compile.  There is an interesting discussion around write only proprties [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695551/write-only-properties-whats-the-point)